# or [self dealloc] work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I make a object that use the camera to decode a bar code. If it was successful it send a delegate message to next action, if not, it only go out, and next screen start to work.

If am I in the last command of the object, can I send [self release] to free the memory? But, the problem is: the retainCount can be more than on one?

Like

```
  ObjectToDealloc *test = [[ObjectToDealloc alloc] init];
  [test doYourJob];
  //can't release here, it broke my program
```

in the last thing that this object do, it run:

```
  -(void)destroyYourself {
     [self release];
     [self dealloc];
  }
```

This will work? I will release the memory? Or I have to make "test" in global visibility (not only function visibility) and do a:

```
   [test release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of instances where I have seen classes that retain themselves in order to keep themselves around until they perform work.  **NEVER, EVER, EVER CALL DEALLOC*.**  Dealloc is not for you, but the runtime.  If you no longer need an object, just appropriately release it.  It is only the runtime's duty to call that method.

Here's an example of some code that I regularly use where the object retains itself and then appropriately releases itself when done with its work:  [UIAlertView+Blocks](https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks/blob/master/UIAlertView+Blocks.m)  This code does this because the object is suppose to stick around, even after it has been released by the instantiating class so that it can run and finish the blocks it was given to execute.

**Except when calling your super's dealloc within your own dealloc, but this goes without saying.*

Comment: I think there's a bug raised with the Clang team to flag the use of `[self dealloc]` - we caught that while debugging a friend's code in the pub. It would save a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 6):

This is not correct memory management. There are a small number of cases when `[self release]` is correct. There are no cases where `[self dealloc]` is correct (you should never call anyone's `dealloc` except your superclass's in your own `dealloc`).

When you say "it broke my program" above, what do you mean? Does `ObjectToDealloc` perform background processing of some sort? If it does not, then you should always be able to release it at the point you indicate. If it does do background processing, then you need something to retain the object until it is done, and then release it. Every so often, the best approach is to retain and release `self`, but usually you have some other thing do it like an `NSOperationQueue` or the like.

The more likely issue here is that you are handling memory management incorrectly in `ObjectToDealloc` and that when it deallocates it crashes. What is the crash?

The key thing to remember is that you never say "destroy this object right now" in ObjC. You say "I'm done with this object." When everyone is done with the object, then it is destroyed by the runtime.